# The use of 'contract'

Tags: word-usage

Is it right to say 'He is contracted with a virus which causes his immunity to be weak against diseases'? Can the word 'contract' be used with 'with'? Thanks.

Comment: He contracted a virus which has lowered his immunity against other diseases.

Comment: *Contract with* is a different sense of *contract*, that of entering into a formal contract. "We have contracted with Acme Products to provide our widgets."

Comment: @StoneyB are you sure you wouldn't just say "We have contracted Acme Products to provide our widgets."?

Comment: @IanMacDonald As far as I know, you can say both. The version with *with* emphasizes the mutuality of the relationship, the one without is equivalent to *engage* or *hire*.

Answer (score 1):

In the everyday English that I've been exposed to, you would not normally use the wording "He is contracted with a virus..." The most common ways of expressing that part of the sentence are probably "He contracted a virus..." or "He has contracted a virus..."

As StoneyB notes in a comment beneath the question, "contract with" is a common way of describing making a business deal with someone, but it doesn't normally occur in settings where the sense of *contract* is to incur or acquire something undesirable (such as an infection).

The full sentence in the context of becoming infected by a virus might look like this:

> He contracted a virus that caused his immunity against diseases to weaken.

or this:

> He contracted a virus that has weakened his immunity to diseases.